# How should I download my git repo to newly setup PC?

Tags: git, github

I backed up my local repo of my old pc to GitHub, I have reinstalled windows and installed git in it ,I now want to download my files and folders I backed up on GitHub. How should I do it ?

I have neither done any initialisation nor configured username and email.

Should I initialise and set a new local repo and ssh key and clone the GitHub repo ? Will I face any problems in future while updating the repo ?

**Also if possible I would like to use my old ssh key and same branch as I heard cloning would setup a sub branch.**

**I would like to inform that I am still new to git and github, not a regular git and github user so knowledge is limited on the topic.So please suggest a solution accordingly.**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First set up your username and email in your local git setup, Open a git bash and run these commands…

```
git config --global user.name "YourUserName"
git config --global user.email "YourEmail@example.com"
```

Now, Just clone the repos that you want from your GitHub account. Using the command

```
git clone "URL of your repo"
```

If you can't find the repo URL. Refer this screenshot.

[image: Repo URL IMG]

Do it for all project repositories.

For Authentication while cloning your repo (if it is private) or pushing the changes, if you don't have personal access, create another token from `Profile->Settings->Developer Settings->PersonalAccess Token->Generate New Token.` (Give the required permissions to this token).

Rerer [this](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=video&cd=&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=2ahUKEwja66SZ08_5AhXL2TgGHaoRAN0QtwJ6BAgSEAI&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.youtube.com%2Fwatch%3Fv%3DRGOj5yH7evk&usg=AOvVaw0ls_jJz5BGpVCwzaKuA19u) tutorial to learn git and GitHub.

PS: It will not change any configuration in your GitHub Account, Neither it will alter anything in your project branch settings.

Answer (score 2):

As long as you have restored your `%USERPROFILE%\.ssh` folder with its original content, you should be able to clone/push/pull your GitHub repositories on your new PC.
And that, without "any problems in future".

Once clone, `git swich yourOldBranch` and go on working.

The `git config --global user.name/email` is to be done only if you did not restore your `%USERPROFILE%\.gitconfig` global Git config file.
And it is only for commit authorship (it plays no role in GitHub remote authentication)

Comment: I believe I haven't restored my %USERPROFILE%.ssh, can you please tell how should I do it ?

Comment: @AbhishekOjha If you have access to your old PC, zip (compress) the `%USERPROFILE%\.ssh` content, and copy also the `%USERPROFILE%\.gitconfig` file. Uncompress the archive to your new PC, as well as copy over the `%USERPROFILE%\.gitconfig`  to your new PC. And you will be all set.